# Cant understand why im getting exception thrown error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* createArr(int len);
/*
Convantional problem in Code:
There is no descreption to main.
Bugs:
1.line 32 - in scanf there is no & to the variable that'll stor the user input, scanf("%d,size") -> scanf("%d,&size")
2.line 33 - should be getchar(); and then the rest of the code. 
3.In createArr:
    1)line 48 - the parameters that malloc is getting is wrong - the function needs the total amout of bytes, so for int you need to mul the inputed amount by 4
      and the casting is to int and not a int type pointer. int * pArr = (int*)malloc(size) -> int * pArr = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * size).
    2)line - in scanf() the storing variable is wrong,the storing variable should be the index in the array, scanf("%d",size) -> scanf("%d",*(arr + i)). (Another thing is that you didnt use & for the integer size)
    3)line 54 - should be getchar() after scanf() and then the rest of the code.
    4)line 57 - using the function free() in the wrong way, the function is realising spesific places in the computer memory and the function is used only when you dont need the memory the you allocated your self to the array.


*/
int main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    int* pArr = 0;

    printf("Enter a number of cells: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    getchar();
    pArr = createArr(size);
    printf("The array is at address %p: ", pArr);
    free(pArr);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/*
Function creates an array
input: number of cells in the array
output: pointer to the new array
*/
int* createArr(int size)
{
    int * pArr = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter a number for index %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",*(pArr + i));
        getchar();
    }
    return pArr;
}
```

---

The code is homework i got in class,i need to find errores in the code fix them and explain them.

The Problem:
When im executing the code im getting the following error: ***Exception thrown at 0x0FE98E2E (ucrtbased.dll) in q5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD. occurred***

after using break points i found out that the problem is occuring in this part of the code:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("Please enter a number for index %d: ",i);
    scanf("%d",*(pArr + i));
    getchar();
}
```

in the function creatArr

I want to understand why im getting this error so i can fix it.

Comment: Remove asterisk from `*(pArr + i)`, or use `&pArr[i]`

Comment: ... and compile with warnings

Comment: and learn now to use a debugger, which will probably help you to figure out such problems.

Comment: @PaulHankin Not needed. A C compiler must give a message when you try to implicitly assign an `int` to an `int*`. If no compiler message was given, the compiler is broken and must be replaced.

Comment: One comment at the beginning doesn't look right - you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` at all, and definitely not to `int`.

Comment: @Lundin True for the `(int)malloc(...)` but not for the `scanf("%d", *(pArr+i))`. Perhaps the advice should be "compile with warnings and read them"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the hard-to-read pointer arithmetic syntax `*(pArr + i)` but instead use indexing `pArr[i]`, then the bug is much easier to spot.

scanf expects an address but you pass a value. Change the code to this:

```
scanf("%d", &pArr[i]);
```

Also never cast the result of malloc, since this hides away bugs. In your case, it created a new bug since you accidentally cast to `int`. Your compiler must give a diagnostic message there.

Answer (score 1):

Tow major mistakes.

The returned result from malloc is a `void*` don't cast it to `int`(don't cast it or at least cast it to `int*`).

`*(pArr + i)` this is dereferencing a pointer.
`scanf` expects a pointer, in your case you are giving an `int`.
You can remove the '*' and the parentheses or even better, use `&pArr[i]`

Comment: You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` at all in C.

Comment: If you don't do it explicitly it will be done implicitly. The end result is the same but it is more readable.

Comment: Pointless code is not more readable, only harder to maintain. And before C11, it was unsafe, too.

Comment: Took the note. Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

The one that triggers the error you mention is here:

```
scanf("%d",*(pArr + i));
```

For `scanf` you need to provide the *pointer* to the variable you want the input to go, but you provided the *value* of the variable.

You need

```
scanf("%d", pArr + i);
```

or

```
scanf("%d", &pArr[i]);
```

The second problem is more subtle:

In this line you cast the result of `malloc` to `int`, but you probably wanted to cast it to `int*` (`malloc` returns a *pointer*).

```
int * pArr = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

But anyway, in C you don't cast the return value from `malloc`, just write:

```
int * pArr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

But best practice is writing:

```
int * pArr = malloc(sizeof *pArr * size);
```

That way the argument of `sizeof` always matches the size of the type (`int` here).